# Hide or kill Windows Update Prompt via cmd/run

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-server-2019

I am currently having a really stupid issue with some Windows Server: When I connect to it via TeamViewer, I am greeted with this lovely update prompt:

[image]

Loosely translated:
"We have an update for you" - "Windows is a service which requires regular updates to work as intended. Your update is scheduled for 18:01. You can also directly choose "Reboot now", if you're ready.
The options are: "Reboot", "Another time", "OK"

Sadly, I cannot click or tab on anything here because the TeamViewer process may not be allowed to. I have admin rights on the PC with the user I am currently logged in though. Is there any way to kill this prompt via `taskkill` or any other measure? I tried to nuke `dwm.exe` and `explorer.exe`, but these didn't do the trick. Could anyone help me out here? (Rebooting is not an option, because it's a productive server)

Comment: Although not an answer to the actual question: logging off (Win + R -> logoff) worked in my case and left me with a clean desktop, don't know for how long though.

Comment: Can you provide an English translation of the dialog? It's difficult to identify which dialog your asking about, if the contents of the message, are not in English.

Comment: @Ramhound "We have an update for you" - "Windows is a service which requires regular updates to work as intended. Your update is scheduled for 18:01. You can also directly choose "Reboot now", if you're ready. The options are: "Reboot", "Another time", "OK".

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? There is a way to disable that prompt, but if that solution can be used, depends on which version of Windows you are running. You should provide the translation as an [edit] to your question.

Comment: @Ramhound I added both to the question.

Comment: Windows Server 2019 isn't enough information.  What build do you have currently installed?

Comment: @Ramhound Version 1809, Build 17763.3650

Comment: You should be able to set the [`Select the target feature update version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-wufb-group-policy) group policy to `1809` in order prevent the message entirely. However, that policy was added relatively recently, so that policy might not exist on 1809. However, because 1809 has reached the end of service date, the policy likely will simply be ignored. *So I highly recommend updating to a version that is supported.* BLUF: **The way I know to get rid of the message will be ignored since the version reached end of supported.**

Answer (score 0):

When updates have been downloaded and prepared, you have no option but to do the updates at some point.

You can schedule Updates.

You can then defer for a period of time until you can restart.

Much better to schedule restarts at times you can do them.

You cannot practically or usefully turn updates off.

To say Restart is not an option is a very limiting strategy as ALL computers need restarting and down time at some point.